# Cannot create array of refs using useAnimatedRef()

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-reanimated-v2

### Description

Cannot create an array of refs using useAnimatedRef. Below I have mentioned how one can create an array of refs using a traditional useRef but for some reason useAnimatedRef does not recognize arrays. Even when an empty array is placed inside such as const refArray = useAnimatedRef([]) one cannot use .push or any other array methods on the ref. This is a problem because there are times where we need to create arrays of refs. Is there a different approach to making an array of refs that I’m not aware of? I tried plenty of work arounds but none work.

### Code example

code bellow does not work since the array is not recognized.
`const refArray = useAnimatedRef([]) refArray.current.push(SOME_ITEM)`

This is how one would create an array of refs using traditional useRef. This obviously does not work since there is no createRef equivalent for useAnimatedRef()
`const refArray = useRef([...Array()].map(() => createRef()))`

### Package versions

- React: 16.13.1
- React Native: 0.63.4
- React Native Reanimated:
- 2.0.0-rc.0 NodeJS: 12.3.0

Comment: Were you able to find solution? I'm also trying to create an array.